# How do I hide a throbber when ASP.NET client side validation fails?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, throbber

I'm using the ASP.NET login control and I'm displaying a [jQuery throbber](http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/379) when the submit button is clicked. This works fine, but the throbber is visible if client side validation fails and the button is invisible, so the user cannot re-submit the form. How do I hide the throbber if client side validation fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a little tricky but I got this working. First of all, the Login control must be templated, which I expected, but even so the ClientID of the button is inaccessible so I had to add a class selector to it. I first tried to add the throbber and turn it on if validation succeeded using the lightly/un documented Page_ClientValidate() event but that didn't work because the throbber by default subscribes to the button's click event and turns on before validation occurs.

What did work was sticking to the [mini API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) and adding the throbber to the button if Page_IsValid is true. The button's CausesValidation attribute must be true (the default).

javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.login').click(function() {
            if (Page_IsValid) {
                $('.login').throbber({ image: "Images/throbber.gif" });
            }
        });
    });
```

button markup; the only addition from the Login control template is the CssClass attribute:

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="uxLogin" CssClass="login" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much about the detail... why don't you only start the throbber when the client side validation *passes*? As a user I'd be surprised to see a UI element flash up very temporarily, only to be removed again and replaced by an error message.

Comment: That might be a better approach but I still have to solve the same problem of responding to the result of client side validation. I'll try it both ways once I get to that point. However, my main goal is to prevent the user from clicking the damn button umpteen times if the site doesn't respond in 10 nanoseconds. :-)

Comment: @Jamie: So disable the button as soon as the user clicks. Re-enable it if validation fails, or show the throbber if validation succeeds. Yes, you've got to respond to the result of client-side validation - I would have thought that was pretty much a given.

Comment: @Jon It's not a given, it's the question. I don't know how to determine the result of client side validation (on the client side) when using the ASP.NET validation controls. I could easily write my own validation in this case but once I get this working on the login form I want to implement it on forms with many controls.

Comment: @Jamie: Your question was about the throbber, which IMO is putting the cart before the horse. I would entirely ignore the throbber side of things for the moment. Go straight to the root cause: read up on client side validation and how to respond to its results. I don't know a lot about it myself, but I would expect any tutorial or book on ASP.NET validation to go into it.

Comment: @Jon: I appreciate your responses but I wouldn't have asked the question here if the answer were easily found in a tutorial.